# How to do element wise operation of Pandas Series to get a new DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas Series of numbers, lets say `[1,2,3,4,5]`. I want an efficient way to create a dataframe with each combination of series element passed through a function and the result being the corresponding dataframe element

Lets say the function is

```
def f1(a,b):
   return a*b + 5
```

then I want the dataframe to be like below, with each cell being the result of the function call with combination of series element.

```
col_1___2___3___4___5__
row|
  1|6,  7,  8,  9,  10
  2|7,  9,  11, 13, 15
  3|8,  11, 14, 17, 20
  4|9,  13, 17, 21, 25
  5|10, 15, 20, 25, 30
```

The series can sometimes be as much as 500 elements.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```py
def f1(a,b):
   return a*b + 5

s=[1,2,3,4,5]

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=s, index=s)
df=df.apply(lambda x: f1(x.name, x.index))
```

Output:

```py
    1   2   3   4   5
1   6   7   8   9  10
2   7   9  11  13  15
3   8  11  14  17  20
4   9  13  17  21  25
5  10  15  20  25  30
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

#create pandas dataframe with one column "col_" with data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_':list(range(1, 6))})
print(df['col_']) #this is data you provided above.

#Create a new column based on function.
b=1 #constant
df['1_'] = df['col_'].apply(lambda x: x*b+5)
#and another column
df['2_'] = df['col_'].apply(lambda x: x*(b+b)+5)
```